# Datepicker in Salesforce - Year

Tags: visualforce, date

So as part of inbuilt validation , if we enter 8/8/17 ---> Salesforce converts it to 8/8/2017
Similarly , if we enter 7/8/88 --->It becomes 7/8/1988
This occurs before SFDC code is even invoked .

Question - Can we have any validation in place(restricting year range) using the standard datepicker or we need to use jquery datepicker or JS?

Comment: This will depend if you would like to show a error on wrong date selection or would like to show only valid years for selection.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i was also facing the same issue. Actually when i was changing the date using date picker the date was changing successfully but when i was manually changing it, it was giving me the error you faced.Actually i associated onkeyup event with the input field taking date values.
 so i would suggest you not to associate onkeyup event with the date field if you have used use onchange event instead.

Thanks,
Yogesh B. Patil